# Cakephp not routing to correct url, leaving url param empty

Tags: url-routing, cakephp-2.0

I am trying to set up a view for my logged in user.  I lifted the code from the cakephp 2.0 manual.  this is the controller code:

```
public function view($id = null) {

    $this->User->id = $id;
    if (!$this->User->exists()) {
        throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid user'));
    }

    $this->set('user', $this->User->read(null, $id));
}
```

When a user with the user_id of 1 logs in, cake doesn't go to /users/1.  Instead it just goes to /users/view.  Here are the routes pertaining to the users controller:

```
Router::connect('/users', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login'));
Router::connect('/users/:action', array('controller' => 'users'));
Router::connect('/users/:id', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'view'));
```

I'm not sure which I have wrong, the route code or the controller code.

**UPDATE**  New controller function:

```
public function view($id = null) {

    $this->User->id = $id;
    if (!$this->User->exists()) :
        throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid user'));

    elseif($this->Auth->login()) :
return $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'view', AuthComponent::user('id')));

    endif;
    $this->set('user', $this->User->read(null, $id));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The page Cake opens after a succesful login is either the page the unauthenticated user tried to open initially or the action set in the `loginRedirect` property of your Auth component in the (App)Controller. As also [documented here](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#identifying-users-and-logging-them-in). In other words, the above code has nothing to do with the behaviour you are describing/requesting.

In this case, since the user_id is only available after a successful login (and thus cannot be set in the `loginRedirect`), you'll need to adjust your login action in your UsersController instead, to become something along the lines of:

```
if ($this->Auth->login()) {
    return $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'view', AuthComponent::user('id'));
}
```

Comment: I see what you are saying, so I took out the code about throwing an exception and used this instead.  It logged in as /users/view/18 and chrome gave me a redirect loop error.  Should I have a redirect command right back to the controller action that it rests inside?  Will add new function to the OP.

Comment: No, you misread my answer. The bit of code should go in your login action, not in your view action.

Comment: Sorry, derp derp moment!  Ok, this successfully logs in with no loop error, however it is still routing to /users/view/18.  I do not understand how to tell cake to go to /users/18.  I really thank you for your help;  as I am actually a noob at programming anything, you have provided me with several ah-ha's that the cakephp manual only made unclear to me.

Comment: @HeatherWalters If that's the URL you want it to go to simply replace the redirect bit to that exact URL syntax, like: `return $this->redirect('/users/' . AuthComponent::user('id'));`. Make sure you have route a that can handle such a request, but as far as I can tell from your posted routes above, this should work just fine.